# What will happen when a gas cylinder is taken to space (vacuum)?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, vacuum, atmospheric-science, ideal-gas

Inside the atmosphere, I guess the atmospheric pressure negates the pressure exerted by the gas that's inside a gas cylinder. However, when taken to a vacuum (space), Will the gas cylinder burst due to the pressure exerted on its internal walls by the gas that is present inside it?

Comment: If one extra atmosphere of pressure difference causes a gas canister to burst, it is either a very, very unsafe gas canister, or someone is filling it far in excess of its rated pressure.

Comment: Re, "...atmospheric pressure negates the pressure...inside a gas cylinder." Depends what you mean by "negates." The pressure that the cylinder must contain is the _difference_ between the absolute pressure inside and the absolute pressure outside. At Earth's surface, the pressure acting on the outside is in the neighborhood of 15 psi or 100 kPa.  The pressure _inside_ a high-pressure gas bottle can be thousands of psi (tens of MPa).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stresses in the wall of a gas cylinder can be estimated by modeling it as a [thin-walked pressure vessel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_vessel#Stress_in_thin-walled_pressure_vessels). The so-called hoop stress is $\Delta Pr/t$, where $\Delta P$ is the pressure difference, $r$ is the radius of the cylinder, and $t$ is the wall thickness. For a cylinder filled to a pressure of 100 [bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_(unit)), for example, the move from Earth’s surface (1 bar) to space (0 bar) would increase the stress by only 1%. As noted in the comments, the cylinder would have to already be at the threshold of failure for this increase to be important. Related scenarios can be considered for different values of pressure and [factor of safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_of_safety).

Comment: Why it is merely geometric and does not depend on the canister material? Or it is just intended to be, to be used in conjunction with the material characteristics?

Comment: Yes, you compare the output stress with a material characteristic (in this case, the strength). It's very typical for mechanics-of-materials problems such as this one to depend on the loading, the geometry, and the material. This offers various ways to achieve success (e.g., change the load type, optimize the geometry, select an appropriate material).